# Conditional value select for repeating nodes

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm new at using XSLT and have encountered a problem with one of my programs. I've tried to solve this with my limited knowledge to no avail. I'm trying to process a XML file to only get US parts. The data contains both Chinese and US parts. The data is contained within repeating nodes.

I've tried conditional statements to restrict the select to only get the US part ID. However, I'm getting IDs for all parts.

This is a sample of the XML input file:

```
<Part>
            <Part_ID>Comp-97531</Part_ID>
            <Country>US</Country>
    <Identification_Data>
        <Product>Finished</Product>
        <ID>12345678909876</ID>
        <ID_Type>CHN-1</ID_Type>
    <Identification_Data>
    <Identification_Data>
        <Product>Finished</Product>
        <ID>123456789</ID>
        <ID_Type>CHN-2</ID_Type>
    </Identification_Data>
    <Identification_Data>
        <Product>Finished</Product>
        <ID>13579</ID>
        <ID_Type>CHN-3</ID_Type>
    </Identification_Data>
    <Identification_Data>
        <Product>Finished</Product>
        <ID>555555555</ID>
        <ID_Type>USA-1</ID_Type>
    </Identification_Data>
</Part>

    <Part>
            <Part_ID>Comp-95137</Part_ID>
            <Country>US</Country>
    <Identification_Data>
        <Product>Finished</Product>
        <ID>1234567812345</ID>
        <ID_Type>CHN-1</ID_Type>
    <Identification_Data>
    <Identification_Data>
        <Product>Finished</Product>
        <ID>987654321</ID>
        <ID_Type>CHN-2</ID_Type>
    </Identification_Data>
    <Identification_Data>
        <Product>Finished</Product>
        <ID>246810</ID>
        <ID_Type>CHN-3</ID_Type>
    </Identification_Data>
    <Identification_Data>
        <Product>Finished</Product>
        <ID>777777777</ID>
        <ID_Type>USA-1</ID_Type>
    </Identification_Data>
</Part>
```

This is the XSLT code I'm trying:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
            <FILE>
        <xsl:for-each select="Part">
            <xsl:call-template name="ProductRecord"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </FILE>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ProductRecord">
        <ID>
      <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Country = 'US'">
          <xsl:if test="Identification_Data/ID_Type='USA-1'">
            <xsl:value-of select="Identification_Data/ID"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </ID>
</xsl:template>
```

The requirement is to get only parts manufactured in the USA with ID_TYPE = USA-1.
    Using the XSLT code, I'm expecting only values for ID_Type = USA-1 that would be 555555555. However, the output I'm getting is like this:

```
  12345678909876 123456789 13579 555555555.
```

How can I restrict the select to only show the USA specific data?
Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start messing with XSLT instructions you should start to get some understanding of XPath as its expression language and there you could simply select `//Part[Country = 'US']` to select the `Part` elements for which the condition `Country = 'US'` in the predicate `[Country = 'US']` holds.

Then with the selected `Part` elements as the context node you can select `Identification_Data[ID_Type = 'USA-1']/ID` to select the `ID` child element(s) of the `Identification_Data` elements for which the condition `ID_Type = 'USA-1'` holds.

To use those XPath expressions in XSLT you can then simply use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:template match="root">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="Part[Country = 'US']"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Part">
      <xsl:copy-of select="Identification_Data[ID_Type = 'USA-1']/ID"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6q/1.

So no need for any `xsl:call-template` or `xsl:choose`, simple XPath selections and match patterns suffice.

Note that I had to fix some of your input markup and also introduced a root element container for the `Part` elements as usually an XSLT input is a well-formed XML document and not a sequence of `Part` or other element siblings.